# почему триггер не работает?

Tags: sql-server

у меня есть таблица в которой два столба id предметов и названия предметов, мне надо создать триггер, который если такого предмета нету в таблице добавлял его, а если есть, то выводил текст, что такой предмет уже есть и не добавлял его
вот мой код

```
GO
CREATE TRIGGER AddingDiscipline
ON Disciplines
FOR INSERT
AS
DECLARE @Subjects VARCHAR(150)
SELECT @Subjects=Subjects
FROM inserted
IF EXISTS (SELECT Subjects FROM Disciplines where @Subjects=Disciplines.Subjects)
BEGIN 
PRINT 'Предмет уже есть'
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: а что за `for insert` если они обычно задаются как `insted of` либо `after` ? Как вы определяете что триггер не работает?

Comment: а, пардон, это для каких то новых версий

Comment: в любом случае надо писать `instead of`, ибо толку то от вашего `after insert` триггера?

Comment: заметьте также, что при вставке нескольких строк разом в inserted будут вставляемые строки, а не одна. так что в `@subjects` у вас попадет только последнее вставляемое значение. Так что если вы передаете на вход `values ('qwe'), ('asd')`, при этом qwe в таблице уже есть, а asd нет,то никакого отката ваш код не сделает. надо джойнить таблицу данных на вставку, если результат есть, то откатывать.

Answer (score 0):

вы пишите триггер `after insert`, который на саму вставку никак не влияет, а требуется вам триггер `instead of insert`.

Далее, следует учесть, что в случае множественной вставки `INSERT ... VALUES ('qwe'),  ('asd');` в таблицу `inserted` попадает не одна строка, а все. Поэтому ваша переменная `@subjects` примет последнее значение из вставляемых строк. Следовательно при множественной вставке результат будет некорректен.

Поэтому, если хотите забраковать всю вставку при наличии совпадающих, то надо джойнить `inserted` на исходную по полю и проводить вставку только в случае, когда выборка не пуста.

```
ALTER TRIGGER trg_DisciplinesInsert ON disciplines INSTEAD OF INSERT AS 


    IF NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM inserted AS i
        INNER JOIN disciplines AS d ON (d.title = ltrim(rtrim(i.title)))
    ) BEGIN
        INSERT INTO disciplines (title) 
        SELECT DISTINCT ltrim(rtrim(title)) FROM inserted;      
    END
    ELSE PRINT 'Есть дубликаты';
```

откат тут в целом не нужен, ибо в случае дубля фактическая вставка не производится.

как вариант, вы можете вставить только новые строки

```
ALTER TRIGGER trg_DisciplinesInsert ON disciplines INSTEAD OF INSERT AS 

    INSERT INTO disciplines (title) OUTPUT inserted.*
    SELECT ltrim(rtrim(i.title))
    FROM inserted AS i
    LEFT JOIN disciplines AS d ON d.title = ltrim(rtrim(i.title))
    WHERE d.id IS NULL
```

В итоге, если вам таки надо вывести сами дубли текстом, то можно сначала зайджойнить новые строки с имеющимися и результат вставить во временную. Потом глянуть, если есть старые, то вывести их (в новых версиях использовать string_agg). Новые строки вставить, можно также вывести вставку через OUTPUT.

```
ALTER TRIGGER trg_DisciplinesInsert ON disciplines INSTEAD OF INSERT AS 

    DECLARE @dups TABLE (old_id int null, title varchar(255) );
    set nocount ON;

    INSERT INTO @dups (old_id, title) 
    SELECT d.id, ltrim(rtrim(i.title))
    FROM inserted AS i
    LEFT JOIN disciplines AS d ON d.title = ltrim(rtrim(i.title));      
        
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @dups WHERE old_id > 0) BEGIN
        DECLARE @x VARCHAR(MAX) = ( STUFF((SELECT ', ' + title FROM @dups WHERE old_id > 0 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''));
        PRINT 'dups: ' + @x;;
    END;
    
    
    INSERT INTO disciplines (title) OUTPUT inserted.*
    SELECT title FROM @dups WHERE old_id IS NULL;
```